# Stack, Heap на уровне железа

Tags: c#, clr, jit

Хочу прояснить ситуацию про хранение и обработку данных в виде стека и хипа. Не могу уложить в уме, как работает данная система на уровне железа...

**1**. Heap - это пространство памяти на Жестком диске или ОЗУ? Возникает он во время JIT компиляции, где отсеиваются ссылочные типы и скидываются в хип или же статичен, как сборка в виде Exe-Шника?

**2**. Stack - Храниться в Хеше процессора или ОЗУ? Возникает только во время компиляции и после очищается?

Буду благодарен за линки на тех. литературу, где это можно прояснить. Спасибо.

P.S. Читаю Рихтера - CLR via C#, что сподвигло на данный вопрос.

Comment: Читаю сейчас https://habrahabr.ru/post/128991/, но не улавливаю сути размещение памяти в регистрах, технически не грамотен, хотел бы построить более глубокую картину в данном вопросе.

Comment: и хип, и стэк размещаются в ОЗУ

Comment: @etki Буду благодарен, если вы распишите процесс на примере компиляции с разделением данных на два хранилища, или укажите источник, где это можно прочесть.

Comment: @Rifter Думаю, вам не помешает прочесть вот это https://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/2192/31/lecture/982

Comment: @etki, вовсе необязательно. Автору стоит почитать книги (можно Таненбаума), т.к. вопросов слишком много и из них видно, что он ничего в них не смыслит (хэш процессора тому пример).

Comment: @ixSci Подскажите пожалуйста, в какой из книг Таненбаума описан мой вопрос?

Comment: Вообще это просто способы хранения данных в ОЗУ и более ничего. На уровне железа стек например поддерживается на архитектуре x86, но на многих других процессорах такого понятия нет и он организуется программно. Собственно программно он очень легко реализуется, все что надо - непрерывный кусок ОЗУ и указатель на текущий элемент (вершину стека) ну и операции с этим указателем по мере надобности. А heap ну просто область или несколько областей памяти и некоторый программный код, который умеет находить в ней свободное место, выдавать объектам и возвращать в список пустых областей когда объект умре

Comment: «Structure Computer Organization» и «Modern Operating Systems». Если хочется только одну, то второй может быть достаточно. Эти книги есть на русском, но их названия найдите самостоятельно.

Comment: Стек https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA   Куча https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0_(%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте попробую объяснить на пальцах.

**Heap** располагается в виртуальной памяти. Он не возникает во время JIT-компиляции (во время компиляции возникает только скомпилованный код), его запрашивает библиотека времени выполнения при старте программы. Пространство под heap не хранится в исполнимом файле, т. к. оно там просто не нужно (память всё равно пустая, зачем хранить нули?)

**Stack** располагается точно так же в виртуальной памяти. Он выделяется операционной системой каждому потоку автоматически. Когда программа стартует, создаётся главный поток, которому операционная система выделяет память под стек.

Главное отличие их -- в том, как они *используются* программой.

---

Виртуальная память для процесса выделяется при старте процесса и хранится то на диске, то в ОЗУ, и перемещается между ними менеджром виртуальной памяти. Механизм виртуальной памяти -- это то, что позвляет программам выделять больше памяти, чем у вас есть физической ОЗУ, и изолирует программы друг от друга, позволяя при падении одной программы не падать всей системе.

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ значительно прояснил мою проблему.

Comment: @Rifter: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло! (Но вы всё же при случае почитайте более серьёзную литературу.)

Comment: По рекомендации @ixSci скачал - "Modern Operating Systems" Таненбаума, надеюсь источник подходящий ;)

Comment: @Rifter: Да, Tannenbaum -- хороший, серьёзный источник. Обязательно прочитайте!